# Refresh/rebuild specific beans during Spring integration testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

Our existing Spring Boot integration setup was using `@DirtiesContext` to rebuild the entire bean pool in-between different test methods.

This was fairly slow, and so we started working with beans that could be "refreshed" or torn down/rebuild *internally* without re-creating the instance.

**The problem** is that only some beans support this. If we control `UsersBean`, we can implement a `UsersBean.refresh()` method and call it in our `@After` method.

But if we have existing beans/classes that don't support refreshing, or we don't control, how can we **conditionally** indicate that certain beans need to be dirtied/rebuilt after a specific test?

Or more succinctly: Is there a way to mark as dirty a *subsection* of your bean pool, for rebuilding, at the end of a test method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is possible, at least within a Spring Boot environment.  The `ApplicationContext` implementation there is a [GenericApplicationContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html) which has the ability to [removeBeanDefinition()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#removeBeanDefinition-java.lang.String-), which can then be re-registered via [registerBeanDefinition()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/GenericApplicationContext.html#registerBeanDefinition-java.lang.String-org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition-).

This even cascades through to remove beans that hold a reference to the bean that's being removed (the implementation of this can be seen in [DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean()](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/c037e75f26ac5ef69e4d5fc3045e101ca674dcaf/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java#L546)).

For example if `Bean1` is referenced by `Bean2` :

```
@Component
public class Bean1 {

}

@Component
public class Bean2 {
    @Autowired
    public Bean1 bean1;
}
```

Then a test can remove `bean1` from the context, and see `bean2` replaced as well:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class BeanRemovalTest implements ApplicationContextAware {
    @Autowired
    private Bean1 bean1;

    @Autowired
    private Bean2 bean2;

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test1():");
        System.out.println("  bean1=" + bean1);
        System.out.println("  bean2.bean1=" + bean2.bean1);

        resetBean("bean1");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test2():");
        System.out.println("  bean1=" + bean1);
        System.out.println("  bean2.bean1=" + bean2.bean1);
    }

    private void resetBean(String beanName) {
        GenericApplicationContext genericApplicationContext = (GenericApplicationContext) applicationContext;
        BeanDefinition bd = genericApplicationContext
                .getBeanDefinition(beanName);
        genericApplicationContext.removeBeanDefinition("bean1");
        genericApplicationContext.registerBeanDefinition("bean1", bd);
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
            throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

This shows both bean instances being replaced:

```
test1():
  bean1=hello.so.Bean1@61d6015a
  bean2.bean1=hello.so.Bean1@61d6015a

test2():
  bean1=hello.so.Bean1@2e570ded
  bean2.bean1=hello.so.Bean1@2e570ded
```

(If the `resetBean("bean1")` is commented out, it is the same instance both times round).

There are bound to be edges where this doesn't work out - e.g. if another bean is holding onto a reference obtained from `ApplicationContext.getBean()`.