How to avoid Spring beans that use @Scheduled or JMS/Kafka listeners that are in a cached test context from being active?
When writing integration tests with @SpringBootTest in an application that uses @Scheduled for period tasks, or has JMS or Kafka listeners, the following can happen:

Test 1 starts. An application context is created and added to the test context cache.
Test 1 ends. The application context and all its beans remain "active" in the test context cache.
Test 2 starts. Because there is a slight difference between the beans started in both tests (I know we should minimize this to benefit from the context caching, but sometimes unavoidable), a new application context is created and also added to the test context cache.

While test 2 runs, the @Scheduled beans, or any of the listeners are still "active". So it can happen that a listener not from the "current" application context would pick up a message or execute a scheduled task. This could lead to flaky tests.
Similarly, a test can already end while some async behavior would still continue in the background.
What are people using to avoid this?
I was thinking about adding an interface to such beans called TestSuspendable with a suspend() and resume() method that via a JUnit 5 extension would suspend such beans at the end of each test and resume them at the start of each test. But I don't like that I need to change production code just for testing like this. So I would like to hear if there are better alternatives.

From the context, I think you can use DirtiesContext annotation to run your next test with a fresh Spring application context.  But because I have no control over what test is run in which order, I would then follow up with TestMethodOrder annotation and Order annotation to ensure the context is cleaned for the correct following test

It is indeed the case that @DirtiesContext removes the application context from the test cache, but that would just make everything very slow. Not a viable solution unfortunately.

Well, DirtiesContext was sufficient for me, so i stopped there; now I got interested to check if it was possible to only refresh a subset of beans, so I came across this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54356616/16034206. Maybe you can take a look and see if it works?

As a quick hack what you could try is to create a junit5 listener, that gets access to the applicationcontext. Upon start of the tests if will obtain all beans of type Lifecycle and if not started call start. The same when all tests end you can call stop. That should (temporarily) stop the listenercontainers and schedulers to halt.

The beans involved (listener containers and schedulers etc.) generally all implement the Lifecycle interface from Spring. So as a quick hack you could create a JUnit5 listener for the BeforeAllCallback and AfterAllCcallback to respectively start and stop those beans. That should stop the listening and scheduling of tasks.
public class LifecycleExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

  void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
    var ctx = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context);
    Map<String, Lifecycle> beans = ctx.getBeansOfType(Lifecycle.class);
    for (var bean = beans.values()) {
      if (!bean.isRunning()) {
        bean.start();
      }
    }
  }

  void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
    var ctx = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context);
    Map<String, Lifecycle> beans = ctx.getBeansOfType(Lifecycle.class);
    for (var bean = beans.values()) {
      if (bean.isRunning()) {
        bean.stop();
      }
    }
  }
}

You could even make it easier by obtaining the LifecycleProcessor from the ApplicationContext and delegate the stopping/starting to that component.
public class LifecycleExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

  void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
    var ctx = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context);
    var lp = ctx.getBean(LifecycleProcessor.class);
    lp.start();
  }

  void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) throws Exception {
    var ctx = SpringExtension.getApplicationContext(context);
    var lp = ctx.getBean(LifecycleProcessor.class);
    lp.stop();
  }
}

Something along those lines might do the trick. Haven't tested it just typed it from the top of my head. But it probably gives you enough information to proceed.

Had no clue about the Lifecycle class, interesting. Strange that Spring Test does not automatically do this. I have now defined a bean override to use NoOpTaskScheduler which also ensures no @Scheduled annotated beans are active. And then I manually call the method in the tests that test that particular behaviour.

Schedulers will stop as well afaik as the are bound to the Lifecycle interface as well (or rather the extension the SmartLifecycle).
